# Getting started with JUCE for Android

Tags: android, juce

I need to start building an Android app that uses the JUCE libraries.  I'm reading the web site and trying to figure stuff out.

I tried installing JUCE on an Ubuntu 11.04 system, and when I built the IntroJucer app, the menus don't work right (they flash open when I click with the mouse but then disappear).  Can a JUCE app for Android be built on Mac OS X, or even Windows?

If you are using JUCE to build Android apps, please give me any advice you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a Juce app can be written for Android using either OS X (XCode 4) or Windows (Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and higher). You also have the option of using the Eclipse IDE on either platform.

At the time you posted, Juce was undergoing a major overhaul and the IntroJucer might not have been as stable as it needed to be, especially on systems other than OS X or Windows. You should look into it again. IntroJucer is not required to build a Juce Application (although it can make things easier).

I suggest you first build the Juce Demo application for your platform. If Ubuntu is giving you trouble, try OS X or Windows first. Once you have the Juce Demo running you can move on to IntroJucer. If that works, then try compiling Juce Demo for Android. Your questions can be answered in the Android Juce Forum:

http://rawmaterialsoftware.com/viewforum.php?f=13

Comment: I don't have any trouble building a Windows app from the JUCE project; I'm having trouble building for Android.  I'm trying to use Eclipse and I have it partially working.  Hmm, if I don't get this working soon, I will take your suggestion and try building the JUCE Demo.

Comment: Since you are the only person to give me an answer, I am accepting your answer to give you the points.  I hope anyone reading this will also read my answer, which documents what I figured out.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I have figured out now that I have been working with this stuff for a bit.

All of this is based on the most recent "stable" release of JUCE, which is about ten months old as I write this.  It is quite possible that things have changed (for the better!) in more bleeding-edge releases of JUCE, and when I get a chance I will try a newer JUCE.

- The best platform is Mac OS X.  When I tried Linux I had some issues with Eclipse not working; I still prefer Linux so I'm going to go back and try again, but on Windows and Mac I had no Eclipse troubles.
- Start by installing the Android SDK, and running the updater to grab all the updates.  Also install the Android NDK, and Eclipse.  In Eclipse, install the ADT plugin.
- JUCE sets up an Ant build file that will build all the C++ code for you, automatically.  You need to not mess with this.  I had a problem where there was a task called "setup" and Ant didn't know how to resolve it; the solution was to delete the "setup" task and not touch anything else.  When I was trying to figure out how to solve this issue, I found suggestions here on StackOverflow to run this command: `android update project --path .`  *DO NOT DO THIS* for JUCE.  This re-writes your `build.xml` file and the special JUCE stuff to build the C++ code disappears; then you build and you get a tiny .APK file (about 10 KB) that contains only the Java setup code and no compiled C++, and *does not work*.  So, just to be clear, the solution to the "setup" build problem is to delete that build task and touch nothing else, and *not* to completely replace your `build.xml` file.
- The JUCE build process relies on a Bash shell script to do some work.  On Mac OS X this works great; on Windows, the build fails with an error from `CreateProcess()` because `CreateProcess()` doesn't understand Bash shell scripts.  It should be possible to edit this and make it work, but out of the box it works perfectly on Mac OS X.
- For testing your code on an Android device, you *must* sign your code.  Eclipse makes it easy to build either signed or unsigned .APK file, but the unsigned file is nearly useless.  The only thing you can do with an unsigned .APK is run it in the emulator.

Once I had all the above stuff correct, I had no problems with building the JUCE app for Android.

Comment: That sounds really cool! Just keep in mind that in the last several weeks, JUCE underwent a major revision that streamlined all of the code and changed the way it is integrated into your project (its much easier now).

Although I haven't tried it, JUCE heads are ranting and raving about this new application called "IntroJucer" which lets you set up a project and then automatically create projects targeting each platform (Android included). You still have to download and install the Android SDK, and NDK (and additional tools as required for your IDE, like ADT).

Comment: Oh and don't be shy, post your positive (or negative) experiences in the JUCE Android forum: http://rawmaterialsoftware.com/viewforum.php?f=13

Comment: Of course we are using the IntroJucer.  I had problems with IntroJucer on Linux, but no problems with it on Windows or Mac OS X, and I had no trouble building a Windows or Mac executable file.